# SearchBar in Navigation Bar in iOS7

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a tableview containing all the countries and their flags.  I've been working to add a search bar and had it all working until I decided to move the search bar into the navigation bar allowed in iOS7 (for my purposes, that layout works very well).

Now, the table loads fine, the search bar shows up fine.  As I type into the search bar, I can see the filtered list being built via the console.  All looks good, EXCEPT the search results table never displays. In other words, I don't see the filtered list in a new tableview.

This method is being called to build the filtered list:

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

But the standard method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

never gets called.

As I said, it's working fine when the search bar isn't in the navigation bar.  I have assigned the following delegates and properties in ViewDidLoad:

```
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

I also have:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
// Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
```

}

What am I missing???

Comment: I've done some more testing and have found that:
    -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

is being called.  I tried:
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;

but that didn't work either.  Please help!!!

Comment: Update:  confirmed all delegates are being called, except the key one:  cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Hence, the reason I get no table.  Another observation, when I click in the search bar, the table view never goes dim.

Comment: Isn't anyone out there running into this???

Comment: Has anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue. Everything works fine if I add the searchbar to the tableHeaderView with `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;`

Found out something interesting: the source-tableview doesn't resize properly, so it is overlaying the results-tableview.

My app is universal. If I run it on iPad the source-tableview is covered completely, so I don't see the results-tableview. But on the iPhone it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as Morpheus, and it was due to having `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
 in my viewDidLoad