# SearchBar in Navigation Bar not working

Tags: search, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

For reference, I'm running the below on an iPad with iOS 7.0.4.  The vc is a presented modally as a form page.  The search vc is the second vc on the navigation stack.

My table is setup with a search bar and search display controller and is working fine with the search bar located in the header of the table.  It returns search results just fine...see image:

!http://www.mcartherstkd.com/images/search.png

I make a one line code change in the vc's viewdidload method to move the search bar to the navigation bar:

```
searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
```

and, while the search continues to work (I can see the search results build via the console) the search results table never updates and I end up with this:

!http://www.mcartherstkd.com/images/searchnotworking.png

I am at a complete loss on this one.  I can't see where I'm going wrong...please help!!!

thanks

Comment: In the second picture, is that a searchDisplayController or just a searchbar in the navigationbar? If it's just a search bar then you can do a few different things like make the table view reload the data with NSPredicate. If you are using a searchDisplayController in the navigationbar I think you are going to have to reorganize your searchDisplayController. Can you post code of what you're doing?

Comment: Hi Chris.  It's a searchDisplaycontroller.   All my searches work and update the displays just fine but fail when I set searchDisplayController.displaySearchBarInNavigationBar=Yes.  That's the only code change I make and it breaks a fully functioning search and gives the results in image 2.  I will be happily to share any code you might think would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SearchBar in Navigation Bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980464/searchbar-in-navigation-bar-in-ios7)